# IsolatedStorage doesn't always save my settings

Tags: c#, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

in my Windows Phone 7 application I have some settings that I keep in the IsolatedStorage.
These settings can be changed in a form of my application.
My problem is that these settings aren't always saved. If I exit from the application using home button and then I open it again, sometimes i still see the old settings and not the new ones. This happens randomly, I mean, I do exactly the same thing but sometimes setting are updated and sometimes they're not.

So I did some researches and I found this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save(v=vs.95).aspx

"Data written to the IsolatedStorageSettings object is saved when the application that uses the class is closed. This can occur when the user closes the Web browser, refreshes a page, or browses away from the page. If you want your application to write to isolated storage immediately, you can call the Save method in application code."

So I tried to use Save() function to instanly save the changes in the IsolatedStorage. Now the problem is that when I click "Save" button in my application, sometimes it works and sometimes it throws an exception (completely random, again).
That page says that an exception is thrown only when there's not enough space in my IsolatedStorage, but:

1. My IsolatedStorage is almost empty, there are only three settings and I only update their value.
2. It happens randomly, not always.

**So my question is:
How can I safely save data in my IsolatedStorage being sure that changes won't be lost? Thanks for your attention.**

Comment: There are a couple of things you need to address, and probably provide more info on.  First, if the settings are configured on a form and the user hits the Home button to exit the app, the expected behavior is that any changes made should not be updated unless the user had selected the Save button prior to exiting.  Calling Save() on IsolatedStorage is the correct approach to trigger a save.  Please provide details on the exception that is thrown to help identify the issue you are having when calling Save().

Answer (score 1):

If it happens randomly in your device, make sure that you have enough space physically. The exception that you described seem related to this.

Make sure that the values that you save are basic types like int, double, string.